# using glui menubar

Tags: c++, opengl, glui

I am new to glui. I am not able to create glui menubar. Whenever I create a glui menubar I get following errors:

```
1.cpp:13: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘*’ token
1.cpp: In function ‘void controlcallback(int)’:
1.cpp:42: error: ‘m’ was not declared in this scope
1.cpp:42: error: expected type-specifier before ‘GLUI_MenuBar’
1.cpp:42: error: expected `;' before ‘GLUI_MenuBar’
```

source:

```
int main_window;
GLUI *w1;
GLUI_Listbox *l1;
GLUI_Button *b1,*b2,*b3,*b4,*b5,*b6,*b7,*b8;
GLUI_Panel *p1,*p2;
enum GLUI_MenuBar *m1;

int id;

void init()
{
    glClearColor(0,1,1,0);
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glFlush();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void reshape (int w, int h)
{ 
    GLUI_Master.auto_set_viewport(); 
}

 void  controlcallback( int val)
{ 

    if( val == 1) {
        w1->set_main_gfx_window(main_window);
        m=new GLUI_MenuBar(p1);
    } else {
        w1->set_main_gfx_window(main_window);
    }
}

int main(int a, char **b)
{
    glutInit(&a,b);
    glutInitWindowSize(3000,3000);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);

    main_window = glutCreateWindow("  practice");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);


    GLUI_Master.set_glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    w1=GLUI_Master.create_glui_subwindow(main_window,GLUI_SUBWINDOW_TOP);
    id=w1->get_glut_window_id();
    p1=w1->add_panel("",GLUI_PANEL_RAISED);
    b1=w1->add_button_to_panel(p1,"navigator",1,controlcallback);
    w1->add_column_to_panel(p1,true);
    b2=w1->add_button_to_panel(p1,"naigator",2,controlcallback);
    w1->add_column_to_panel(p1,true);
    b3=w1->add_button_to_panel(p1,"navigator",3,controlcallback);
    w1->add_column_to_panel(p1,true);
    b4=w1->add_button_to_panel(p1,"naigator",4,controlcallback);
    w1->add_column_to_panel(p1,true);
    b5=w1->add_button_to_panel(p1,"navigator",5,controlcallback);
    w1->add_column_to_panel(p1,true);
    b6=w1->add_button_to_panel(p1,"naigator",6,controlcallback);
    w1->add_column_to_panel(p1,true);
    b7=w1->add_button_to_panel(p1,"navigator",7,controlcallback);
    w1->add_column_to_panel(p1,true);
    b8=w1->add_button_to_panel(p1,"naigator",8,controlcallback);
    w1->add_column_to_panel(p1,true);
    GLUI_MenuBar *m1 = new GLUI_MenuBar(id,GLUI_SUBWINDOW_TOP);

    w1->set_main_gfx_window(main_window);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error is exactly as reported by the compiler `1.cpp:42: error: ‘m’ was not declared in this scope` as `m` is really not declared anywhere.

The other error `1.cpp:13: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘*’ token` sound like you forgot to include some glui header for `GLUI_Listbox`.

BTW, you are shadowing the global variable `m1` with `GLUI_MenuBar *m1 = new GLUI_MenuBar(id,GLUI_SUBWINDOW_TOP);`.

Comment: I have changed m with m1 which is pointer of glui MenuBar. I removed the enum also but still getting the same problem. Is it some version problem that my menubar is not working. I am using 2.36 version of glui.